# onTouchListener detecting wrong dynamically created cardview

Tags: android, android-cardview

I have just learnt how to create cardview dynamically. I'm using a button press to create a cardview and i have set onTouchListener to it. When i'm creating only one card onTouchListener is working perfectly but as soon as I'm creating one more card onTouchListener isn't working as expected. When I have 2 cards and I try to move 1st card it's moving 2nd one instead of 1st.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

Context context;
ImageView imageView;
RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
static int pos=0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    context=this;
    relativeLayout=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rl_layout);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}



@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {

        CreateCardViewWithoutImageView();

        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    return true;
}

public void CreateCardViewWithoutImageView(){

    final CardView cardview=new CardView(context);

    cardview.setId(++pos);
    cardview.setLayoutParams((new CardView.LayoutParams(600, 600)));
    cardview.setContentPadding(25,25,25,25);
    cardview.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.MAGENTA);

    relativeLayout.addView(cardview);

}

private final View.OnTouchListener mListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View card, MotionEvent event) {
        // The View (v) here is a CardView as the onTouchListener is set to it
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamsRL = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) ((CardView) card).getLayoutParams();
        float dx = 0, dy = 0, x = 0, y = 0;

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                card.bringToFront();
                dx = event.getRawX() - layoutParamsRL.leftMargin;
                dy = event.getRawY() - layoutParamsRL.topMargin;
            }
            break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                x = event.getRawX();
                y = event.getRawY();
                layoutParamsRL.leftMargin = (int) (x - dx);
                layoutParamsRL.topMargin = (int) (y - dy);
                card.setLayoutParams(layoutParamsRL);
            }
            break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {

            }
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
};
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your `cardview` variable is global. So each time you create a new CardView it's replaced so the listener is always using the last CardView created.
You should do something like:

```
// Note: By the way, you should NOT use a capital letter to name a function
public void createCardViewWithoutImageView(){

    //CardView
    final CardView cardview = new CardView(context);

    //....

}
```

You are going to have the same issue with `layoutParamsRL` as it should be local too.

### EDIT

```
    // Context context; // You don't need to store the context here as you are in the activity
//    CardView cardview; // Don't need to be global
//    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamsRL; // Don't need to be global
    ImageView imageView;
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
    static int pos = 0; // Are you sure it needs to be a static field?

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

//        context=this;
        relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_layout);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {

            createCardViewWithoutImageView();

            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        return true;
    }

    public void createCardViewWithoutImageView() {

        //CardView
        CardView cardview = new CardView(MainActivity.this);

        cardview.setId(++pos);
        cardview.setLayoutParams((new CardView.LayoutParams(600, 600)));
        cardview.setContentPadding(25, 25, 25, 25);
        cardview.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.MAGENTA);
        cardview.setOnTouchListener(mListener);

        relativeLayout.addView(cardview);
    }

    private final View.OnTouchListener mListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {

        float dx, dy; // Moved outside the onTouch method in order to them to keep their value.

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View card, MotionEvent event) {
            Log.d("OnTouchListener", "don't touch me :p");

            // The View (v) here is a CardView as the onTouchListener is set to it
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamsRL = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) ((CardView) card).getLayoutParams();
            float x = 0, y = 0;

            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                    card.bringToFront();
                    dx = event.getRawX() - layoutParamsRL.leftMargin;
                    dy = event.getRawY() - layoutParamsRL.topMargin;
                }
                break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                    x = event.getRawX();
                    y = event.getRawY();
                    layoutParamsRL.leftMargin = (int) (x - dx);
                    layoutParamsRL.topMargin = (int) (y - dy);
                    card.setLayoutParams(layoutParamsRL);
                }
                break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {

                }
                break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    };
```

Comment: if I do that than I cant change card properties like width, height from outside of that method. Any way to get both features?

Comment: I've edited my answer. You need only one `onTouchListener` (I'm using a variable but the Activity itself could implement the interface) as all the variables used by the listener are locals, so the same listener can be reused by all the CardView. (I think you haven't posted all the code of your activity so it maybe need some adjustments). FYI it's generally a bad idea to have everything global and/or static. It's better to encapsulate thing in small functions. :)

Comment: I have updated my code  with some changes as suggested by you.But now my Card isnt responding to touch. Can you please look into the code. thanks for pointing out those little mistakes in my code , I will try to improve.

Comment: Are you sure it's not responding? (I haven't tested my code)
Maybe the problem is because `dx` and `dy` should remain outside the listener (otherwise the value is always 0 when `ACTION_MOVE` is triggered and nothing will move). Put a break point or a log info in the onTouchListener to see if it's responding.
I've updated the code

Comment: *not outside the listener but outside the onTouch method. Like that `dx` and `dy` keep their value

Comment: I had applied Log inside onTouch but didnt find Log message in android monitor.

Comment: do I need to call anything inside onCreateCardviewWithoutImage()?

Comment: You need to add `Log.d("OnTouchListener", "some text to display");` in the onTouch method (as in the code above). Then it should be displayed in the Logcat window when you press on any of the added CardView. Otherwise just put a break point an run your app in debug mode. The app should stop on the break point when you click on a CardView if the listener works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151974/discussion-between-jitendra-purohit-and-eselfar).

Answer (score 0):

1- the variable is global so u need to defined in inside method as mention above 
2- you can easily change its properties with another method and pass it the cardview object as parameter
3- you can keep the global object to represent the selected cardview as in touchevent method will assign the cardview that fire event  to the global and do what u want with it

Comment: I can't understand 2nd and 3rd step.can you please post some code for reference?

Answer (score 0):

//Create the Global object to make use of it in assign new property as u want

```
CardView selectedCardview;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { //....... }
```

//will create inner object

```
public void CreateCardViewWithoutImageView(){
    CardView cardview = new CardView(context);
    //Setting the default property u want:)
    cardview.setId(++pos);
    cardview.setLayoutParams((new CardView.LayoutParams(600, 600)));
    .......
    final CardView tempCardView=cardview;
    cardview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch(event.getAction())
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :
            {
              selectedCardview=tempCardView;
              .........and adding action as u want
            }
             ........... add another cases 
        }

    }
    ...........
}
```

now selectedCardview u use will represent the cardview u touch it and will be easy to set its property as it global

```
void setProperty(){
    /******** add what u want here********/
    selectedCardview.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
}
```

Comment: The inner Card will be final so we cant change its value inside onTouchListener. If I initialize its value with selectedCardView than this error is coming : "The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first."

Comment: that means I cant use two cardviews at the same time. And also I want to change card Properties dynamically (using a seekbar).

Comment: now look to my update i make temp final variable to use it inside onTouch that assign to cardview  then in Ontouch method assign that variable to global one and will solve your problem  don't forget to voting 

Comment: @ahmedshaaban Why do you need a `tempCardView` when the `cardview` could be `final` itself? And the listener is set to the CardView so the `View v` is the CardView already, so you just need to cast it into a CardView. (`CardView innerCV = (CardView) v` something like that)